# Files loaded using $scriptjs or any other asynchronously loader

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

Say I have an AngularJS app which lazy loads controller files (via $scriptjs) and all dependencies when the user navigates to a route. The app contains 3 routes: A, B, C.

If the user routes to A, then B and back to A, are the files for A loaded into memory twice or is the browser smart enough to cache the files and retrieve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser will cache external javascript files. So yes if a user has loaded one of the scripts the browser should recognize that it is cached and not call it again.

If you are using firefox you can see this happening using the firebug extension. In the Net tab of firebug you can see the javascript files that are being loaded for that page. Once they are cached you will see the name of the file in light grey. This means they are cached.